# Java Heartbeat framework

Tags: java, heartbeat

I need to implement a heartbeat-mechanism that sends a 'touch'-message to an external service every X seconds to keep the session alive, if no other messages are sent to the service. I have looked at using things like ScheduledExecutorService or Timer but I need to find something where I can reset the timer/delay when other messages are sent on the session so that I do not send heartbeats when they are not required.

Are there any known frameworks for this type of heartbeat mechanism, as it would seem like a regular heartbeat functionality? Or, can anyone please point me in the right direction to create an efficient solution for my problem based on standard components?

Comment: This sounds way too specific for there to be an existing framework for. Plus, it sounds like your task isn't that hard - I would reconsider using a `Timer` to call some external service - you can make it work and it has a `reset` method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to just skip the heartbeat for a given timer invocation if there was some activity since the last time? Or, what harm is there in sending extra heartbeat messages? My gut tells me you'd introduce more overhead in doing proper synchronisation to communicate with the timer than the extra heartbeats would cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that I could see is to just write your own.  Create an object that can send the 'touch' message, then create a daemon process to do that continuously.

All this should be doable with POJOs and the `Thread` and `Process` classes.  Good luck!

Comment: Yup, went with a `ScheduledExecutorService` and implemented a `reset` method that resets the delay to the next heartbeat. Thanks for all suggestions and comments.